# MongoDB convert String to Int before aggregation in java driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I want to do sum aggregation of a salary which is stored as String in document.
I dont want to convert the string value to int in database itself.
Something like below in mongoDB using java driver.

```
SELECT sum(CAST(amount AS UNSIGNED)) FROM tbl1
```

I tried to cast in acumulator as follows but its giving zero as output.

```
 accumulator = Accumulators.sum("value",  $toInt: "$"+field);
```

I can do it in native mongodb query but I want to do it in java driver.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(group(new BsonNull(), sum("total", eq("$toInt", "$value"))));
AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate​(pipeline);
```

The static imports are from the `com.mongodb.client.model` package.

Optionally, since you are accumulating money, you can consider `$toDecimal` or `$toDouble` *instead of* `$toInt`.

Comment: where is eq method present. Its not int com.mongodb.client.model?

Comment: The `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters` class. `eq` is a static method. Also, `Aggregates.group` and `Accumulators.sum`.

Comment: Does `eq` mean "equal" here? Why could it apply `$toDecimal` to a field?

Comment: @can. In this case it means (I think), that the `$toInt` operator is applied to the documentproperty `value`  and assigned to the field `total`. The definition of [Filters.eq](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html#eq(java.lang.String,TItem)). says: _"Note that this doesn't actually generate a $eq operator, as the query language doesn't require it."_

Comment: _Why could it apply $toDecimal to a field? _ Because sometimes the source value (a number in a string type field) can have decimal values (e.g., "12.59") - so you can use the `$toDecimal` to sum, and get the result as the same data type. Note that MongoDB supports 4 types of number fields - int, long, double and NunberDecimal. And the  default for a number type is a double or an int (depends upon the version of MongoDB and the size of the number).

Comment: _Why could it apply $toDecimal to a field?_ : @can. See my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Could you provide a reference to mongo document(or java-mongo document) about this kind of usage? `Filters.eq` document isn't very helpful to me.

Comment: @can. I am not sure what your question is. But `$toDecimal` is an aggregation operator to convert a field (a string with number or an integer, for example) to a decimal number. See the usage with a native query at [$toDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal/). For example: `{ $toDecimal: "5.56" }`.

Comment: I mean the usage of `eq`, as every document I read tells me it would test if `$toInt` equals `$value`, where this `$toInt($value)` come from?